# Yesod Resources and URL type safety automation

Tags: haskell, yesod, type-safety, template-haskell, hamlet

I've been on a mission to learn everything about Yesod, and I'm (somewhat) stuck on the routing system and it's relation to subsites and cross-route linking in general. The first thing I would like to address is the "`ResourceR`" pattern found throughout the route definitions and Hamlet links.

I notice that the "type" itself (`ResourceR`) is never addressed or referenced outside of Yesod's TH DSL's. Does this mean that it's only really used as a dummy type, meant only for leveraging Haskell's type safety in referencing Yesod links? I also notice that the functions `getResourceR`, `postResourceR` etc. are **vital** for the app to work, yet it's not explicit where their definitions are used in boilerplate app code. Does Yesod simply reduce the calls to `@{ResourceR}` to the appropriate function?

I keep feeling like I should be defining `ResourceR` myself as a datatype, when in fact it's generated and reduced internally by Yesod.

So my question is: do the "resource types" referenced in Hamlet and Route code get automatically generated and reduced by Yesod's DSL's?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at `http://www.yesodweb.com/book/basics`, it describes the `Resource` datatypes clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Yesod indeed expands what it sees in the the routes file (or what you type in the parseRoutes function in a quasiquotes section), and gives the server the appropriately named get or post function (by prefixing "get" or "post" to the resource name).  All that you need to do is create the get/post function, and the framework will use the routes to call the function for you.  You need only specify the path and request type.

Centralizing all path information in one location like this makes it easy for you to debug where an individual request will go (think of what the alternative spaghetti code would look like).  The forced name standards also keep your code understandable, and code generation removes some of the repetition (ie- it helps you adhere to the [dry principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).